# nodeJs basic authentication issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, basic-authentication, servicenow-rest-api

I'm getting no proper response while make an API request to external API using basic authentication (username and password) in nodejs (javascript)

I used the below code and the response is "undefined", not sure what is missing here.
But I was able to make a request using postman tool without any issues.

```
const request = require('request')
const user = '*****';
const pass = '*****!';

const url = 'https://servicenow.com/api/table'
var options = {
    url: url,
    auth: {
        username: user,
        password: pass
    }
};
 
request.get(options, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) { 
        return console.log(err); 
    }
    console.log(body.url);
    console.log(body.explanation);
});
```

Response:

```
undefined
undefined
```

Comment: What do you get when you log `err`, `res` and `body` ?

Comment: it did not print those values

Comment: It logged `undefined` for all three ?

Comment: can i know what is the correct method / syntax to make a request in javascript ?

Answer (score 3):

if your api right with postman you can do like this based on photo

1. `send` a request
2. click on `code`
3. select `nodejs- Request`
4. `copy`

[image]

Comment: with some tweaking, this worked for me