# get request has an error that the url is wrong while the api actually works

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make a client-side get request to this api:
'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip='
here we need to pass zip+apiKey to get a response:
[image]

I am doing this in the browser and I'm getting response successfully:
[image]

here in the app trying to do that but I am getting error in the 'get request' that the url or the get route is wrong:

```
    /* Global Variables */
let baseURL = 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=';
let apiKey = '####';
let appID='&appid=';


// Create a new date instance dynamically with JS
let d = new Date();
let newDate = d.getMonth()+'.'+ d.getDate()+'.'+ d.getFullYear();

document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', performAction);

function performAction(e){
  const temperature =  document.getElementById('zip').value;
  const userResponse = document.getElementById('feelings').value;
  const getTemp = async (baseURL, temperature, appID,apikey)=>{
      
      const res = await fetch(baseURL+temperature+appID+apikey)
    try {

    const data=await res.json();
    return data;
    
    }  catch(error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    // appropriately handle the error
     }
  }
   getTemp().then( res =>{ console.log(res);
   
    postData('/add', {temperature: temperature, date: newDate, userResponse: userResponse});
    updateUI('/all');})
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-leaf-0bvpd?file=/src/index.html

Comment: Add the protocol portion of the URL: `https://api...`

Comment: it was there and gave same error so I removed it

Comment: I noticed 'Not Secure' - use `http://api...`

Comment: @RandyCasburn it's the same

Comment: What's the error? Still bad URL? Use the EXACT same URL that you show in the browser image and see if you still get an error - but ensure you include the URL.

Comment: do you get correct data when you use `postman`? @maimohamed

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi - the OP clearly states he gets the correct result in a browser window.

Comment: if you can get the correct result in postman you can do like this answer 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66189681/nodejs-basic-authentication-issue/66190159#66190159  just select `fetch` item and add `http`  to the url @maimohamed,

Comment: I attached a sandbox for clarification

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi I think the link you attached has a solution for a 'post request' here I am dealing with get request

Comment: I told you, send a correct requst with postman after taht do like the answer @miamohamed

Comment: why should I make a postrequest?

Answer (score 0):

Here your are missing one thing 'http' protocol as browser automatically adds that. In your code make these changes:

```
let baseURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=';
let apiKey = '####';
let appID='&appid='
```

Comment: it was there and I removed it because there was the same error

Comment: did you check the URL that you created using log?

Comment: I checked it in the browser

Comment: Not in browser. Try to console.log(baseURL+temperature+appID+apikey). Is it matching the actual URL?

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi Yes these steps will be really helpful for you 'Mai' . Also , include in your code body parser if you haven't added that already.